# DirectShow Pushsource for demuxed data. Do I need 2 sources

Tags: networking, directshow, pins

I am getting 2 byte * (one audio and one video, already demuxed). So it is not a standard file.

Can I create a pushsource with 2 input pins. one for audio and one for video. 
I know the subtypes and all.

I am getting this data of the networks. So it is a live source.

Comment: Yes you can, however since it's a source filter which provides data to the graph they should be output pins, not input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create both single push source with two pins, and two push sources with single pin on each. Both ways it can work out. With two pins on one filter make sure to stream/deliver data from different threads.